# Fullcalendar start time and end time in month mode

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar v2.2.5. And I found that the start and end datetime is YYYY-MM-DD 08:00:00. Why is not start from 00:00:00?
Please see the attachment below
[image]

Comment: Because your local time is GMT+8. The actual date is in UTC (GMT) format.

Comment: @A1rPun Aha, that's it. Thank you so much. I thought it was a bug...